# Sveltekit adding images doesnt update before server restart

Tags: sveltekit

Created a Sveltekit node website, using mysql database with prisma,

The page is updated with scrapers, that also downloads images, and store them in client/scraped_images/folder01/image1.jpg and so on.

Issue is, after a scrape, it saves and shows the mysql data fine, but its 404 with images, until i do a node server reboot and cleans the cache (the images ARE there).

I load the images like this:

```
<img
                        src={'/scraped_images/' +
                            auk.imageDirectoryName +
                            '/' +
                            auk.imageFolder +
                            '/image01_thumb.jpg'}
                        alt="Auktions billede"
                        class="rounded-md h-[100px] sm:h-[120px] w-[220px] object-cover"
                    />
```

The question is, why does it do this? and how do i fix it so, when it automaticly updates at night, i dont have restart node server and have to have people cleaning browser cache to see it?

Thanks